# See only owner's data in ListAPIView

Tags: permissions, django-rest-framework

I have a view deriving from ListAPIView, with the following permissions:

`permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrSuperuser, )`

IsOwnerOrSuperuse is defined as such:

```
class IsOwnerOrSuperuser(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    return obj.user == request.user or request.user.is_superuser
```

(which is very similar to the tutorial)

Now, when a normal user queries my view, it can see everyone's objects. Isn't the permission applied to every single object in the list? How can I enforce this type of behaviour with minimal overhead?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `has_object_permission` is not applied to list and create endpoints, only retrieve, update and delete where there is only single instance. To filter lists, you should use `get_queryset` to filter the objects.

```
class BlogList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrSuperuser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Blog.objects.filter(user=user)
```

To apply further permissions, you need to implement `.has_permission(self, request, view)`....